# overridding back button in android works only for the index page

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, cordova, overriding, back-button

I am trying to use the back button in android to go to the main page every time the user press the back button and when the user is not logged in, the application should exit. I have tried this coded but it only works in index page and in the other pages, back button acts as it has been disabled. i am using phonegap for this application.

$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

```
function onDeviceReady() {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

}
```

}

I kept the following function on .js file.

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert('Back Button!');
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("loggedInData") == "undefined"
            && window.localStorage.getItem("loggedInData") == "") {
        //location.href = 'main.html';
        alert('LoggedIn');

    } else {
        alert('not logged in');
        navigator.app.exitApp();

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my brief experience with Phonegap to get this to work i had to call the onDeviceReady before document.ready (i know this doesnt make sense but it worked for me on a small project).

Also if i am assigning different functions to the back button based on a page, i like to clear them first before rebinding them each time by chaining off().on() as below:

```
$(document).off("deviceready").on("deviceready", PhoneGapReady);
function PhoneGapReady(e) {
    $(document).off("backbutton").on("backbutton", backHandler);
}
function backHandler(e) {
    //back button pressed do something if you like
}
```

Also in the if statement for localstorage, should that be 'or' instead of 'and'?

Comment: It is not working...When i click the back button in main page, i get the error saying:10-19 10:30:19.915: E/Web Console(580): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova at undefined:1 What should i do now?

Comment: I  get the following error when i do the above code...10-19 11:19:42.108: D/CordovaWebView(963): KeyDown has been triggered on the view
10-19 11:19:42.108: D/CordovaWebView(963): >>> loadUrlNow()
10-19 11:19:42.144: D/CordovaLog(963): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova
10-19 11:19:42.144: D/CordovaLog(963): undefined: Line 1 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova
10-19 11:19:42.144: E/Web Console(963): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova at undefined:1

Answer (score 0):

To make the back button work for every pages of your app add the following code to every html pages.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("deviceready", PhoneGapReady);
 function PhoneGapReady(e) {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
```

}

```
function onBackKeyDown(){
//your codes for back button
}
```

and add

*`<script>type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"</script>`*

to the every page...
As i am using cordova-2.0.0,i have used that.